# Why do we have $\sum_n P(|X|>n)<\infty$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In Resnick's Probability Path, page 221, I find the following passage:

Let's assume that $\{X_n\}$ are iid, and that we have $E(|X_1|)<\infty$.
Also, $X´_n=X_n 1_{[|X_n|\leq n]}$.

> $\sum_n P(X´_n\neq X_n)=\sum_n P(|X_n|>n)<\infty$, since
>   $E(|X_1|)<\infty$.

Why do we have $\sum_n P(|X_n|>n)<\infty$?

I thought of using Markov inequality: $\sum_n P(|X|>n)\leq \sum_n \frac{E(|X_n|)}{n}=E(|X_n|)\sum_n \frac{1}{n}$

The problem is that the series in the last step doesn't converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $E(|X_1|)=\int_0^\infty P(|X_1|>t)\,dt$. (If this is unfamiliar, prove it!) Now write the integral as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{n-1}^nP(|X_1|>t)\,dt$. Because $t\mapsto P(|X_1|>t)$ is non-increasing, you now have the comparison
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X_1|>n)\le E(|X_1|)\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X_1|>n-1).
$$

Comment: MAny thanks John! ;)

Comment: By the way John, $\int^{\infty}_0P(|X_1|>t) dt$ or $\int^{\infty}_0P(|X_1|\geq t ) dt$ ? I'm trying to prove the equation, but when I use fubini: I have $\int_{[0,\infty)}\int_{|X_1|>t}$ and transform to $\int_{0<|X_1|} \int_{[0,|X_1|)}$. There's the slight problem that the dist of $|X_1|$ may have mass at $0$...

Comment: They are equal, because $P(|X_1|>t)=P(|X_1|\ge t)$ for all but countably many $t$, hence for Lebesgue a.e. $t$.

Comment: Thanks John D. ;)